# What is happening with g.root-servers.net.?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have just found out that `192.112.36.4` (`g.root-servers.net.`) neither responds to requests, nor responds to pings.

```
.                        3600000      NS    G.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
G.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     192.112.36.4
```

I checked http://www.internic.net/domain/named.root, which is an up2date list of root servers and the IP address is correct. I always was under the impression that those root servers are redundant to the point where it is impossible that there is downtime. According to http://root-servers.org there are worldwide six locations where servers are located, so I would assume I am correct with that assumption.

My question is if `g.root-servers.net.` is in any way different from all the others, or special,
**and if I am supposed to not get a DNS response from it for any reason?**

Comment: G-root is run by the US military.

Comment: So only the US military has access to it, or what do you want to tell me?

Comment: You asked what is different or special about it.

Comment: I did. I thought you were implying something.

Comment: `neither responds to requests, nor responds to pings` - Ping is only a useful tool when and if you know that you should get a response from the target. You're statement that it doesn't respond to pings implies that you think that you should get a response. Now as it turns out, all of the other root servers respond to pings so it's a pretty safe assumption that g.root-servers.net should as well, but that's an assumption nonetheless. Only use ping when you absolutely know that the target should respond, otherwise you're wasting your time tilting at windmills.

Comment: FWIW, the g.root server _was_ responding to DNS over TCP requests during the outage - it was only for UDP that it was unavailable.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> I always was under the impression that those root servers are redundant to the point where it is impossible that there is downtime. According to http://root-servers.org there are worldwide six locations where servers are located, so I would assume I am correct with that assumption.

Even were there not an undocumented outage for G, that's an incorrect assumption:

- The Anycast IP addresses may represent multiple physical sites, but it is [undesirable for abuse events in one region to cascade into failures in others](https://lists.dns-oarc.net/pipermail/dns-operations/2015-December/013911.html). If a site buckles, that traffic is not going to be shifted into another.
- Shared network links where abuse directed at a root server is present may very well choke before infrastructure closer to a root server does.

Lastly, we have the human element. G was down [across the board](https://atlas.ripe.net/dnsmon/group/root?dnsmon.session.color_range_pls=0-66-66-99-100&dnsmon.session.exclude-errors=true&dnsmon.type=server-probes&dnsmon.server=192.112.36.4&dnsmon.zone=root&dnsmon.startTime=1460547600&dnsmon.endTime=1460644800&dnsmon.ipVersion=both), but there has been no officially disclosed reason for why at this time. A widespread failure of this type typically points at a deliberate action or a catastrophic failure in the central administration.

As the users of Serverfault do not represent the administrators of the root servers, your best bet is to watch for an [official statement](http://www.root-servers.org/). In the meantime, the link above is sufficient to demonstrate that there was a total outage for G. The internet continued to operate because one root being down doesn't have a significant impact in the larger picture.

---

Update from the DoD NIC:

```
Regarding yesterday's G-root outage:

Like many outages, this one resulted from a series of unfortunate events.
These unfortunate events were operational errors;  steps have been taken to
prevent any reoccurrence, and to provide better service in the future.
```

https://lists.dns-oarc.net/pipermail/dns-operations/2016-April/014765.html

Answer (score 9):

I was with someone from Ripe in a meeting yesterday afternoon, and my first impression after she had shown me the problems was that the rootservers suffered from a misconfiguration in the firewall.

The things I noticed:

- TCP responces worked fine. (https://atlas.ripe.net/dnsmon/group/root?dnsmon.session.color_range_pls=0-66-66-99-100&dnsmon.session.exclude-errors=true&dnsmon.type=server-probes&dnsmon.server=192.112.36.4&dnsmon.zone=root&dnsmon.startTime=1460573400&dnsmon.endTime=1460649600&dnsmon.ipVersion=both&dnsmon.isTcp=true)
- UDP responces were dead.
- All Ripe Atlas probes reported the same problem. The problem was not specific to one region.
- BGP routing towards the network was just fine. No problems there.

The fact that UDP didn't work and TCP did work suggests that someone tried to block UDP packets above a certain size or something like that.

During the outage I have done several tests and all UDP tests failed, not only tests with a answer size larger then 512 bytes.